# Scroll top with slimscroll plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax

I used `slimScroll` on my web page with the content is added by AJAX.

If I scroll down the scroll then reload with more content (AJAX load), the scroll bar itself always keep its position the same as before.

I wonder if the `slimScroll` has any function that I can call to scroll to top after loading the new content?

Answer (score 25):

I don't think the `scroll` option described by @rochal is going to work right now, as it doesn't appear to be used by [the version currently up on GitHub](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll/blob/master/jquery.slimscroll.js). Instead try `scrollTo` or `scrollBy`.

To scroll to the top:

```
$('#elem_id').slimScroll({ scrollTo : '0px' });
```

Conversely, if you want to scroll to the bottom, then the following should work:

```
var scrollTo_val = $('#elem_id').prop('scrollHeight') + 'px';
$('#elem_id').slimScroll({ scrollTo : scrollTo_val });
```

Comment: Works Great for the scroll to bottom.

Comment: I love you.  I truly do.  Well you just helped me out a lot with this :)

Answer (score 5):

Since version 1.0.0 if you need to scroll to the top you can use build in **[scrollTo](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll)** method:

`$(element).slimScroll({ scrollTo: '0' });`

Comment: Thanks Rochal for your great plugin, it's really one of the best one i can find on the internet, but it seem that this way cannot resolve my issue.The scrollbar still keeps its position after i reload the content using ajax

Comment: I have this exact same issue. The content is scrolled to the top, but the scrollbar remains in it's position. Anyone have any additional thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2):

This code has run for me.

```
var scrollTo_int = $('#elem_id').prop('scrollHeight') + 'px';
$('#elem_id').slimScroll({scrollTo : scrollTo_int });
```

This will take scroll bar at the bottom position and also take the content at the bottom of the div.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can use javascript to solve this problems...

```
document.getElementById("element-id").scrollTop = document.getElementById("element-id").scrollHeight;
```

`element-id` is the `id` of your content area(normally its `div`)..

execute this code when new content is appended to your `div`

Answer (score 0):

For me, the answer suggested by the author @rochal does not work, neither [`scrollTo`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12445507/2126442) nor [`scroll`](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll/issues/29#issuecomment-8501328) as slimScroll configuration parameters: both scroll the content but not the handle, and one of them even destroys the container height in my case.

Instead, this worked for me:

```
// let's assume the plugin was initialized with this class name present:
$('.slim-scroll').slimScroll(config);

// then this is the solution.
$('.slimScrollDiv.inQuestion').find('.slimScrollBar').css({ top: 0 }).end().find('.slim-scroll').get(0).scrollTop = 0;

// -----------------------------
// once more, with explanations:
$('.slimScrollDiv.inQuestion')        // this is the ‹div› wrapped around our .slim-scroll element by the plugin. It always has the 'slimScrollDiv' class name.

  .find('.slimScrollBar')             // first address the handle. The order is important because we're going to break the chain at the end.
    .css({ top: 0 })                  // 'scroll' it.
  .end()                              // stay in the jQuery chain; go back to the last jQuery collection before find().

  .find('.slim-scroll')               // address the content.
    .get(0)                           // leave jQuery terrain, get the DOM element.
      .scrollTop = 0                  // scroll it.
;
```